# how to execute a method specific to a function in a different class from the main form class? (c#)

Tags: c#, class, function, forms, methods

May be my lack of awareness of some key programming concept on polymorphism or interface inheritance etc. this should be easy. I'm a novice.

I have a separate class in C# program called tts. Now I defined a function in it called speak. here is it:

```
class tts

{ 

     public void speak() 
     {

        Process process1 = new Process();
        process1.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\eSpeak\\command_line\\espeak.exe";
        process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "hello";

        process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        process1.Start();
        //process1.Kill();
    }
}
```

When I call this function from main form under an event (`listBox1_SelectedIndexChange`), it runs fine. What this program does is read "hello" every time I scroll through my list box. But I want to kill process1 when I scroll to next item in listbox. when I implement the `process1.Kill()` (by uncommenting the kill method) in speak function, the program doesn't read "hello". What happens is that the process1 get killed immediately. So I would not implement method Kill() there under the speak function. But I want to kill process1 from main form when I change index of listbox (`listBox1_SelectedIndexChange`). Here is my main form code.

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tts obj = new tts();
        obj.speak();
    }
```

What I want to do is this:

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tts obj = new tts();
        obj.speak();
        process1.Kill();
    }
```

which of course wont work since process1 is under the scope of function speak in class tts. how to execute `process1.Kill()` from main form?

I would appreciate the basic code itself more than technical terms on what to do.

Comment: thanks adeel for editing and formatting the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Speak` method could return the process it's started:

```
public Process Speak()
{
    // Code as before
    return process1;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextToSpeech obj = new TextToSpeech();
    Process process = obj.Speak();
    process.Kill();
}
```

If you want to actually start the process in one event and kill it in another, you'll probably want an instance variable in your form which maintains the last-started process:

```
private Process speechProcess;

private void StartButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: consider what you want to happen if there's already
    // a process running
    TextToSpeech obj = new TextToSpeech();
    speechProcess = obj.Speak();
}

private void StopButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Possibly change the UI so that the button will be disabled
    // when there's no process running
    if (speechProcess == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    speechProcess.Kill();
    speechProcess = null;
}
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, this ties the `TextToSpeech` class to the idea of using a process. It would be provide better encapsulation if you made `TextToSpeech` responsible for the process management, so you could ask that to start and stop appropriately. Then you'd change the `speechProcess` variable above from a `Process` type variable to `TextToSpeech`.

Comment: I think that the Process instance should be an private implementation detail of the `TextToSpeech` class. There could be implementations that don't use any external processes at all. I'd suggest makeing the TextToSpeech-instance itself an instance variable of the form and implement a "StopSpeak" method (see my response below)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is create seprate class to manage process

here is example code how it look like :

```
class processmanagement
{
  Process p;

  public Process startprocess()
  {
    p = new Process();
  }

  public void killprocess(Process p1)
  {
    p = p1;
    if(p!=null)
      p.kill();
  }
}
```

or

```
class processmanagement
{
  Process p;

  public void startprocess()
  {
    p = new Process();
  }

  public void killprocess()
  {
    if(p!=null)
      p.kill();
  }
}
```

Comment: you were just a minute ahead of me:).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see any use of the `processmanagement` class: This class does nothing more than the `Process` class itself.

Comment: @MartinStettner  - this a example for all process he is going to manage in his project rather than targeting single problem, i pasted code to make him understand what he is lacking in his design

Comment: @Pranay Rana: You don't need any additional class for process management since the `Process` class is meant exactly for this purpose. Everywhere you would use your `processmanagement` class you could use the `Process` class in exactly the same way (even with less code, since in your case, you have to 1) create the `processmanagement` class *and* 2) call `startprocess` instead of simply creating a `Process` class). Your class is just code duplicate (which is considered bad design...).

Answer (score 2):

Make `process1` an instance variable of your `tts` class and implement a method `stopspeak` there, like:

```
class tts {
  Process process1;
  public void speak() { .... }
  public void stopspeak() {
    if (process1 != null)
      process1.Kill();
    process1 = null;
  }
}
```

Additionally you should similarily keep track of your current tts class in you main window so that you can write

```
private tts obj;

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (obj != null) {
      obj.stopspeak();
      obj = null;
    }
    obj = new tts();
    obj.speak();
}
```